# Why there are many tensorflow.python.xx APIs used in tensorflow repos

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow-model-garden

I found TensorFlow repos extensively use `tensorflow.python.xx` APIs, but there are no docs for such APIs. For example, I found many codes in TF model gardens use the `tensorflow.python.keras.backend` API, like [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/image_classification/resnet/resnet_model.py).

What are these APIs used for, and when should I use these APIs.

I also find some of them has equivalent APIs, e.g. `tensorflow.python.keras.backend` v.s. `tensorflow.keras.backend`. What's the difference between the two versions?